# Need to fetch a MySQL result

Tags: mysql

I have following MySQL table structure,

```
    id   product_id       filter_tag_id     
14      1               48  
17      3               49  
18      10              49  
19      10              54  
20      11              49  
21      11              55  
22      12              49  
23      12              56  
24      9               48  
25      9               52  
26      6               48  
27      6               53  
28      7               48  
29      7               56  
30      8               48  
31      8               53 
32      13              48  
33      13              52  
34      14              48  
35      14              54
36      14              55
37      15              48  
38      15              55
```

i need to fetch only those product_id's which have same filter_tag_id's,
For example only one product_id (9 and 13) having the same filter_tag_id (48 and 52), so I need to fetch only product_id 9 and 13, I'm trying following query, but no success yet.

```
select product_id from filter_data where filter_tag_id=52 AND filter_tag_id=48;
select product_id from filter_data where filter_tag_id in (52,48);
```

First query return no result and second one returning wrong results

Comment: have u tried "GROUP BY"

Comment: `product_id = 13` also has `filter_tag_id IN (48,52)`. How come this isn't included in the desired results?

Comment: yes 13 is there also,9 i had told for example only..

Answer (score 0):

use `GROUP BY`

```
Select product_id,COUNT(DISTINCT filter_tag_id) filter_match 
from filter_data where filter_tag_id in (52,48)
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING filter_match = 2
```

the value of `filter_match` is count you will pass `in` condition

Comment: This will return rows having even only one value in (48,52)

Comment: Select product_id,COUNT(DISTINCT filter_tag_id) match 
from filter_data where filter_tag_id in (52,48)
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING match = 2 limit 1

Comment: please try this query @amrit

Comment: displaying error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match
from filter_data where filter_tag_id in (52,48)
GROUP BY product_id
HAVIN' at line 1 "

Comment: Select product_id,COUNT(DISTINCT filter_tag_id) filter_match 
from filter_data 
where filter_tag_id in (52,48) 
GROUP BY product_id 
HAVING filter_match = 2 
limit 1

Comment: try this query @amrit

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to find only `product_id`s having `filter_tag_id` values equal to `48` **and** `52` **and** nothing else but these two values, then try:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM mytable
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN filter_tag_id = 48 THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN filter_tag_id = 52 THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN filter_tag_id NOT IN (48,52) THEN 1 END) = 0
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ff31/19)

Comment: thx it is working,but same question what will happen if there would be one more or so on fields in filter_tag_id,for example if i need to fetch 1 product_id where product_id consists 3 filter_tag_id's?

Comment: @amrit You have to use additional conditions in this case I'm afraid.

Comment: @amrit Are you looking to find product_ids having *any* 3 filter_tag_id's *or* 3 *specific* ids?

Comment: i m looking for all the product_id's that have both filter_tag_id(48 AND 52 AND so on)

Comment: @amrit Then you have to specify each separate id your are looking for in some predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Use self-join. It looks like more complicated than `GROUP BY`, but it is faster than group-by. Because with `GROUP BY` approach, those which only has 48 or 52 should be groupped that is not unneeded rows.

```
SELECT t1.product_id
FROM filter_data t1 INNER JOIN filter_data t2 ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id
WHERE t1.filter_tag_id = 48 AND t2.filter_tag_id = 52;
```

Comment: an accetable answer but what  will happen if there would be one more or so on  fields in filter_tag_id,for example if i need to fetch 1 product_id where product_id consists 3 filter_tag_id's?

Comment: Do you mean you need to find more than 2 values? eg) 48, 52, 56? In that case, you need to generate the query dynamically by given values.

Comment: yes exactly, query is already dynamically genrated,but would be the query then? " SELECT t1.product_id
FROM filter_data t1 INNER JOIN filter_data t2 ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id ON t2.product_id = t3.product_id
WHERE t1.filter_tag_id = 48 AND t2.filter_tag_id = 52 AND t3.filter_tag_id = 56;"

Comment: @amrit Yes. exactly. Do self-join 3 times. (`t3` is not in above query. I think it is typo)